# How to change the Mifare Classic 1k key A and Key B

Tags: c#, nfc, smartcard, rfid, mifare

I am using a Mifare classic 1k reader, and it comes with the default key A and B which is:

```
FFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Using the Key A to read and write works. but I want to change the keys.

Is there anyway to get the correct access bits for the sector and what is the format?

What I have done now is,

```
<newKey>+ access bits + <oldKEY>
212121212121078069FFFFFFFFFFFF
```

The access bits `078069` I got from reading block 7 of sector 1, which is like this:

```
000000000000FF078069FFFFFFFFFFFF
```

But there is error.

Are the access bits incorrect or is the format wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the access control settings of the sector trailer, you may need to authenticate with key A or key B to be able to write keys. See the section 8.7 (and specifically 8.7.2) of the datasheet at http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MF1S70YYX.pdf on how to encode/decode the access control bits in the sector trailer.

Comment: Thanks. i managed to change keys using the default access bits for the trailer and it worked. but is there a way to change the access bits? i read access condition for the sector trailer, but i can't get the idea yet.
btw, i m using mifare 1k, not 4k.

Comment: @Liban please don't ask additional question within a comment. Accept the answer and ask additional questions the usual way.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I am having the same issue. can you please help me out

Comment: This is not how [so] works. I don't provide individual help here. Furthermore, the time that I used MIFARE is now **far** in the past; I'd have to look it up myself, so sorry, no.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is, if access bits have permission (and your's seems like they do), is to write:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAA078069BBBBBBBBBBBB
```

where AAAAAAAAAAAA and BBBBBBBBBBBB are the NEW A & B keys, respectively. (You never write the old keys, you authenticate with onthem first).

When you read, using key A, you'll always get

```
000000000000078069BBBBBBBBBBBB
```

Key A will allways be masked

Comment: do u mean "Key B" when u write "Key A will allways be masked"?